# Add a sumtotal line to a area plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a area chart which I am happy with. I am trying to overlay a thick solid line along the top of the area chart.

The plot is website sessions by channel, where each channel is  group (fill) in the area chart. The idea being I'll show a solid line chart for total sessions with a very heavy alpha showing what the source of these sessions are.

By data look like this (Since ggplot functions depend on the data structure)

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Month       : Factor w/ 24 levels "May-2015","Jun-2015",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Channel     : Factor w/ 6 levels "Facebook","Youtube",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sessions    : num  5065 4226 4779 5736 6350 ...

> head(dataset, n = 20)
      Month  Channel Sessions
1  May-2015 Facebook     5065
2  Jun-2015 Facebook     4226
3  Jul-2015 Facebook     4779
4  Aug-2015 Facebook     5736
5  Sep-2015 Facebook     6350
6  Oct-2015 Facebook     6199
7  Nov-2015 Facebook     8474
8  Dec-2015 Facebook     8340
9  Jan-2016 Facebook    11376
10 Feb-2016 Facebook    11290
11 Mar-2016 Facebook    13255
12 Apr-2016 Facebook    16693
13 May-2016 Facebook    14618
14 Jun-2016 Facebook    14208
15 Jul-2016 Facebook    14016
16 Aug-2016 Facebook    14978
17 Sep-2016 Facebook    14559
18 Oct-2016 Facebook    10583
19 Nov-2016 Facebook     6930
20 Dec-2016 Facebook     8918
```

My area chart:

```
timeline <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions,fill = Channel, group = Channel)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.7) +

# This piece right here is where I tried to add a solid line
  geom_line(data = dataset, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions, group = Month)) +

  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

I was successful up to and including `geom_area(alpha = 0.7)` since this produces a nice area chart.

But the next line causes unexpected behavior:

```
geom_line(data = dataset, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions, group = Month))
```

I was hoping to see a continuous line overlayed on top but instead got a series of broken up vertical bars. See the black lines on the bottom of the output. I tried adding/removing the command `group = Month` but that didn;t change anything:[image]

How can I add a solid line via a line chart along the very top of my stacked area chart to denote total sessions?

Comment: Put another way the very top of the current chart should have a solid thick line denoting total traffic volume, since the areas below are stacked

Comment: @Axeman thanks, I gave that a try but nothing changed `timeline <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions,fill = Channel, group = Channel)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.3) +
  + stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun.y = sum, geom = 'line')`

Comment: D'oh! I had two plus signs ++, it works. Thank you!

Comment: What is "group = 1" within aes in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you show some nice data there, it isn't actually reproducible. From the help files we can do:

```
series <- data.frame(
  time = c(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4)),
  type = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 4),
  value = rpois(16, 10)
)
ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = type))
```

To calculate the sum, we'll have to actually sum up those areas, and this can be done with `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = type)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line", size = 2)
```

You can add `aes(group = 1)` to the `stat_summary` if needed. That will makes sure the calculation is done just for `x` and `y` with no further grouping and the line is connected. It overrides the automatic grouping which happens when you set an aesthetic to a factor. This will also help if `x` is a factor, like in your example.

Using `geom_line` like you did, creates multiple values per x coordinate (one for each `Channel`).[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For fun, to see what happens, I tried group = 2. Actually, I got the same results. What is the deal with group numbers here? I also experimented by leaving group command out and the chart produced undesirable results. So group is certainly needed, just trying to understand what the numbers denote

Comment: The number is irrelevant, it just sets the group to a constant, i.e. you are overriding the automatic grouping which happens when you set an aesthetic to a factor (like `x` in your case).